# Error: Cant't find end of central directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx, data-uri

I am trying to open my base64 file as docx which is created with react-docx library and for that I am using another library react-file-viewer, but I get the following error: "Error: Cant't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://...".
I also tried it with react-iframe but unfortunately browsers don't support docx files and it works but it downloads the file instead of displaying. And I need it to be displayed.

This is my code:

```
<FileViewer
  fileType='docx'
  filePath={`data:application/docx;base64,${file}`}
/>
```

If anyone could help me with that. I am looking for the solution for many days and can't find any.